# Spry menu background image - mouseover not shown

Tags: javascript, html, css, dreamweaver

I modified the `SpryMenu` to show a gradient image as `background`. Unfortunately, when I check the menu, and I mouse over on a link, it does not highlight as it did with `background-color`.

Below is the CSS file.

```
/* The outermost container of the Menu Bar, an auto width box with no margin or padding */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal
{
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 100%;
    cursor: default;
    width: 1100px; /* Change to the width of your own menu bar */
}

/* Menu items are a light gray block with padding and no text decoration */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal a
{
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0.5em 1.2em;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: url(../imagenes/fondo_spry.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

/* Set the active Menu Bar with this class, currently setting z-index to accomodate IE rendering bug: http://therealcrisp.xs4all.nl/meuk/IE-zindexbug.html */
ul.MenuBarActive
{
    z-index: 1000;
}
/* Menu item containers, position children relative to this container and are a fixed width */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal li
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 24px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
/* Submenus should appear below their parent (top: 0) with a higher z-index, but they are initially off the left side of the screen (-1000em) */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 100%;
    z-index: 1020;
    cursor: default;
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: -1000em;
}
/* Submenu that is showing with class designation MenuBarSubmenuVisible, we set left to auto so it comes onto the screen below its parent menu item */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul.MenuBarSubmenuVisible
{
    left: auto;
}
/* Menu item containers are same fixed width as parent */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul li
{
    width: auto;
}
/* Submenus should appear slightly overlapping to the right (95%) and up (-5%) */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul ul
{
    position: absolute;
    margin: -5% 0 0 95%;
}
/* Submenu that is showing with class designation MenuBarSubmenuVisible, we set left to 0 so it comes onto the screen */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul.MenuBarSubmenuVisible ul.MenuBarSubmenuVisible
{
    left: auto;
    top: 0;
}

/*******************************************************************************

 DESIGN INFORMATION: describes color scheme, borders, fonts

 *******************************************************************************/

/* Submenu containers have borders on all sides */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul
{
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    table-layout:auto:;
    text-align:center;
}
/* Menu items that have mouse over or focus have a blue background and white text */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal a:hover, ul.MenuBarHorizontal a:focus
{
    background-color: #960;
    color: #FFF;
}
/* Menu items that are open with submenus are set to MenuBarItemHover with a blue background and white text */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal a.MenuBarItemHover, ul.MenuBarHorizontal a.MenuBarItemSubmenuHover, ul.MenuBarHorizontal a.MenuBarSubmenuVisible
{
    background-color: #960;
    color: #FFF;
}

/*******************************************************************************

 SUBMENU INDICATION: styles if there is a submenu under a given menu item

 *******************************************************************************/

/* Menu items that have a submenu have the class designation MenuBarItemSubmenu and are set to use a background image positioned on the far left (95%) and centered vertically (50%) */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal a.MenuBarItemSubmenu
{
    background-image: url(SpryMenuBarDown.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 95% 50%;
}
/* Menu items that have a submenu have the class designation MenuBarItemSubmenu and are set to use a background image positioned on the far left (95%) and centered vertically (50%) */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul a.MenuBarItemSubmenu
{
    background-image: url(SpryMenuBarRight.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 95% 50%;
}
/* Menu items that are open with submenus have the class designation MenuBarItemSubmenuHover and are set to use a "hover" background image positioned on the far left (95%) and centered vertically (50%) */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal a.MenuBarItemSubmenuHover
{
    background-image: url(SpryMenuBarDownHover.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 95% 50%;
}
/* Menu items that are open with submenus have the class designation MenuBarItemSubmenuHover and are set to use a "hover" background image positioned on the far left (95%) and centered vertically (50%) */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul a.MenuBarItemSubmenuHover
{
    background-image: url(SpryMenuBarRightHover.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 95% 50%;
}

/*******************************************************************************

 BROWSER HACKS: the hacks below should not be changed unless you are an expert

 *******************************************************************************/

/* HACK FOR IE: to make sure the sub menus show above form controls, we underlay each submenu with an iframe */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal iframe
{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1010;
    filter:alpha(opacity:0.1);
}
/* HACK FOR IE: to stabilize appearance of menu items; the slash in float is to keep IE 5.0 from parsing */
@media screen, projection
{
    ul.MenuBarHorizontal li.MenuBarItemIE
    {
        display: inline;
        float: left;
        background: #FFF;
    }
}
```

Heres is the HTML:

```
<? require ("includes/config.php");
?>

<script src="SpryAssets/SpryMenuBar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarHorizontal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<ul id="MenuBar1" class="MenuBarHorizontal">
  <li><a href="<? echo (HTTP_RAIZ);?>">Inicio</a>  </li>
  <li><a href="#">&iquest;Quienes somos?</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Propiedades</a>  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Servicios</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Tips &amp; N
  ovedades</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cont&aacute;ctenos</a></li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var MenuBar1 = new Spry.Widget.MenuBar("MenuBar1", {imgDown:"SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarDownHover.gif", imgRight:"SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarRightHover.gif"});
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: Please provide a HTML code for the same.

Comment: Just added vishalkin. Hope some can help me.

Comment: Change the location of image from "ul.MenuBarHorizontal a" into "ul.MenuBarHorizontal". And the issue was solved. But now it does not work for IE. Only worked in chrome and mozilla. Any comments to solve this?

Comment: Change CSS but now is not working in IE.
ul.MenuBarHorizontal
{
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 margin-left: auto;
 padding: 0;
 list-style-type: none;
 font-size: 100%;
 cursor: default;
 width: 1100px;
 background-image: url(../imagenes/fondo_spry.jpg);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
ul.MenuBarHorizontal a
{
 display: block;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 0.5em 1.2em;
 color: #FFF;
 text-decoration: none;
}

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the typo in the float property of iu.MenuBarHorizontal li.MenuBarItemIE? And another in the table layout property towards the middle of the file.

Comment: typo corrected f/loat  --> float. Error still remaninig at web page,

Answer (score 0):

Got it solved!
The issues was not on the HTML or other CSS files. It was on the spry menu CSS file itself. Compare the code above vs the code corrected below. I add the background-image lines into other classes. And to solve the IE issue, I adeded some lines to the HACK IE portion. Enjoy!!

```
@charset "UTF-8";

/* SpryMenuBarHorizontal.css - version 0.6 - Spry Pre-Release 1.6.1 */

/* Copyright (c) 2006. Adobe Systems Incorporated. All rights reserved. */

/*******************************************************************************

 LAYOUT INFORMATION: describes box model, positioning, z-order

 *******************************************************************************/

/* The outermost container of the Menu Bar, an auto width box with no margin or padding */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal
{
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 100%;
    cursor: default;
    width: 1100px; /* Change to the width of your own menu bar */
    background-image: url(../imagenes/fondo_spry.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

/* Menu items are a light gray block with padding and no text decoration */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal a
{
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0.5em 1.2em;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Set the active Menu Bar with this class, currently setting z-index to accomodate IE rendering bug: http://therealcrisp.xs4all.nl/meuk/IE-zindexbug.html */
ul.MenuBarActive
{
    z-index: 1000;
}
/* Menu item containers, position children relative to this container and are a fixed width */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal li
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 24px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
/* Submenus should appear below their parent (top: 0) with a higher z-index, but they are initially off the left side of the screen (-1000em) */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 100%;
    z-index: 1020;
    cursor: default;
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: -1000em;
}
/* Submenu that is showing with class designation MenuBarSubmenuVisible, we set left to auto so it comes onto the screen below its parent menu item */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul.MenuBarSubmenuVisible
{H
    left: auto;
}
/* Menu item containers are same fixed width as parent */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul li
{
    width: auto;
}
/* Submenus should appear slightly overlapping to the right (95%) and up (-5%) */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul ul
{
    position: absolute;
    margin: -5% 0 0 95%;
}
/* Submenu that is showing with class designation MenuBarSubmenuVisible, we set left to 0 so it comes onto the screen */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul.MenuBarSubmenuVisible ul.MenuBarSubmenuVisible
{
    left: auto;
    top: 0;
}

/*******************************************************************************

 DESIGN INFORMATION: describes color scheme, borders, fonts

 *******************************************************************************/

/* Submenu containers have borders on all sides */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul
{
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    table-layout:auto:;
    text-align:center;
}
/* Menu items that have mouse over or focus have a blue background and white text */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal a:hover, ul.MenuBarHorizontal a:focus
{
    background-color: #960;
    color: #FFF;
    background-position:top;
}
/* Menu items that are open with submenus are set to MenuBarItemHover with a blue background and white text */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal a.MenuBarItemHover, ul.MenuBarHorizontal a.MenuBarItemSubmenuHover, ul.MenuBarHorizontal a.MenuBarSubmenuVisible
{
    background-color: #960;
    color: #FFF;
    background-position:top;
}

/*******************************************************************************

 SUBMENU INDICATION: styles if there is a submenu under a given menu item

 *******************************************************************************/

/* Menu items that have a submenu have the class designation MenuBarItemSubmenu and are set to use a background image positioned on the far left (95%) and centered vertically (50%) */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal a.MenuBarItemSubmenu
{
    background-image: url(SpryMenuBarDown.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 95% 50%;
}
/* Menu items that have a submenu have the class designation MenuBarItemSubmenu and are set to use a background image positioned on the far left (95%) and centered vertically (50%) */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul a.MenuBarItemSubmenu
{
    background-image: url(../imagenes/fondo_spry.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: 95% 50%;
}
/* Menu items that are open with submenus have the class designation MenuBarItemSubmenuHover and are set to use a "hover" background image positioned on the far left (95%) and centered vertically (50%) */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal a.MenuBarItemSubmenuHover
{
    background-image: url(../imagenes/fondo_spry.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: 95% 50%;
}
/* Menu items that are open with submenus have the class designation MenuBarItemSubmenuHover and are set to use a "hover" background image positioned on the far left (95%) and centered vertically (50%) */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul a.MenuBarItemSubmenuHover
{
    background-image: url(../imagenes/fondo_spry.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: 95% 50%;
}

/*******************************************************************************

 BROWSER HACKS: the hacks below should not be changed unless you are an expert

 *******************************************************************************/

/* HACK FOR IE: to make sure the sub menus show above form controls, we underlay each submenu with an iframe */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal iframe
{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1010;
    filter:alpha(opacity:0.1);
}
/* HACK FOR IE: to stabilize appearance of menu items; the slash in float is to keep IE 5.0 from parsing */
@media screen, projection
{
    ul.MenuBarHorizontal li.MenuBarItemIE
    {
    background-image: url(../imagenes/fondo_spry.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
        display: inline;
        float: left;
        color: #CCC; 
        padding-bottom: 0px; 
        padding-top: 0px; 
        /* background: #FFF; 
        height: 35px;*/
    }
}
```